# Packaged Apps: error with example from http://developer.chrome.com

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create my first hello world described here:

http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/first_app.html

but I got error 
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
Permission 'app.window' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.

also, I had to add --enable-platform-apps to my shortcut to chrome...

What did I do wrong?

Thank you
edit:
this is manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "description": "My first packaged app.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["experimental", "app.window"],
  "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
}
```

chrome is 21.0.1180.88

Comment: can you share the manifest file you used? Also, what is the Chrome version you are using?

Comment: p.s. I copy pasted it from step 1

Comment: It's working for me great on Chrome Canary (v.23) - I guess you might want to install it and test it there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the current stable release -- Chrome 21 -- which does not include the `app.*` APIs.  If you want to use those APIs before they are incorporated into the stable release, you can develop your app using [Chrome Canary](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs/), which is several version ahead of the stable release.

Note that the URL you reference has `/trunk` in it, indicating that it is documentation for the most recent (unstable) version of Chrome.

Comment: Ok..thank you, now with Canary it works, is there any manual or how to start writing my first app that will work with current stable release? I mean, this is very confusing if you just starting and want to experiment with Apps...Thank you

Comment: Agreed -- it appears that Google doesn't have a version of their docs for the stable release anymore, or else it's extremely difficult to find. I just tried looking up doc pages I have used many times before, and they now give 404 errors. Google is pushing hard to make documentation for their new `app` API, but they seemed to have prematurely thrown out the documentation for the current stable API. I am a little shocked that the "Chrome Extensions" link on the [Chrome developers home page](https://developers.google.com/chrome/) is completely broken.

Answer (score 0):

When i changed the manifest file in the example as per the manifest file shown in this link http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps.html i am able to install this example app in chrome stable version i.e 21.0.1180.83.

My final manifest file content is

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "description": "My first packaged app.",
  "version": "1",
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "window.html"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "calculator-16.png",
    "128": "calculator-128.png"
  }
}
```